# "Ploc" and weird exception message strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, odata, modelstate

**Context**

I'm using OData and Model State validation to generate error messages. When attempting to get the actual reason for a validation error, I pull out the exception message.

I have the following code:

```
        foreach (var field in modelState)
        {
            details.AddRange(field.Value.Errors.Select(error => new Error
            {
                Target = field.Key.ToCamelCase(),
                Message = error.ErrorMessage,
                InnerError = new Error
                {
                    Message = error.Exception.Message
                }
            }));
        }
```

The problem is with error.Exception.Message.

**Examples**

When I send the request

```
        {
            "assisfdgfsdgnedBy": true
        }
```

This is the value of Message:

> "!ynECc!The parameter 'assisfdgfsdgnedBy' in the request payload is not a valid parameter for the operation 'Count'. Ploc Ploc !"

When I send the request

```
{
    "assisfdgfsdgnedBy": truedsg
}
```

The value of Message is

> "!ieOni!Invalid JSON. Unexpected token 'truedsg'. Ploc !"

Occasionally I'll even have endings such as

> "Ploc ploc plo !"

and it seems the first part of "!something!" changes for each error type but is consistent for requests with the same error.

**Question**

What are these values, why are they in the exception message, and how do I easily remove them without affecting other "normal" exception messages?

Answer (score 0):

I've arrived at a solution to strip these values, but I still have no idea what's causing them.

Code is as follows:

```
public static string CleanPlocPloc(string message)
{
    message = Regex.Replace(message, "^!.+?!", "");
    message = Regex.Replace(message, @"\.(\s(Ploc|Plo))*\s!$", ".");

    return message;
}
```